# Block SIGINT from terminating program

Tags: c, ctrl, reverse-shell

I need some help on C program - it is a reverse shell (https://github.com/arturgontijo/remoteShell/blob/master/reverseShell.c) I made few changes, like put that all in a loop and some sleep pattern + put some argument to pass directly IP and PORT now that thing works very good it's stable (problem that cannot autocomplete stuff with TAB I don't really care) BUT what I really care is that this thing will break if on target machine I press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> the program just exits itself. Now I used this example to block <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> calls:

```
/* Signal Handler for SIGINT */
void sigintHandler(int sig_num) 
{ 
    /* Reset handler to catch SIGINT next time. 
       Refer http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal */
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler); 
    printf("\n Cannot be terminated using Ctrl+C \n"); 
    fflush(stdout); 
} 

signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
```

I got this example online and put it on my loop as well, but still from client pressing <kbd>ctrl+C</kbd> breaks program. I wonder `dup2()` is responsible for that or something because on simple C program this actually worked fine.

Comment: That portion of code looks OK. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: ^ Hi - code looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/oKf5aP4

Comment: You can not make arbitrary function calls from within a signal handler.  [Footnote 188 of the C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188) even states "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows for the calling of only async-signal-safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).  Note that `printf()` and `fflush()` are **not** async-signal-safe.  Your online source where you got that code is a bad source.

Comment: adding to andrew's comment, `write` is async-signal-safe and if the file descriptor written to is line buffered or unbuffered there is no need for a flush: `char m[] = "hi\n"; write(stdout, m, sizeof(m));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sigetops family of functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sigsetops) to manipulate the signals sent into your application.

So for your example you could use:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sigset_t block_set;

    sigemptyset(&block_set);

    sigaddset(&block_set, SIGINT);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &block_set, NULL);

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Running Example: https://repl.it/repls/RelevantImaginarySearchservice

You can unblock the signal at a later time by calling

```
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &block_set, NULL);
```

Comment: Hmm still nothing, I think I will fork it or something so a process will be eliminated instead of main thing